# Licensing information on Blender Python script that uses Blender API (python) and my won APP

Tags: python, licensing

Hi experts!
I am new to the development of add-ons for the Blender and I am not any expert in deducing license terms and conditions.

I have a 3D-printing slicer application written in C++ which is complete in itself. I have exposed the APIs in Python using PyBind11, to extend Python. Let me call this application **3DP-APP**

The way things work is, Python add-on to blender acts like an intermediary. The data from blender APIs is converted into XML or JSON or STLs etc. and sent to the 3DP-APP APIs. 3DP-APP is used as a computational library for 3D printing process. It returns data in neutral file formats, which is then used to feed Python APIs of blender, which creates geometries, renders and animates.

I like to use Blender for visualization of slicing and animation of the whole 3D printing process. So, I need to write an Add-On to Blender that will call both the **Python APIs of Blender** and the **APIs of 3DP-APP**

I have the following questions.

1. **Q1 - Shall I retain the propriety and have my commercial license for the 3DP-APP?**
2. **Q2 - Do I need to open the source of the 3DP-APP also, if I need to ship the Python script  for the Add-on to commercial customers.**

Please note that

1. I do not redistribute blender binaries
2. I do not modify any Blender source code
3. The Python Add-on script alone that I write is open source
4. I can not open the source of my proprietary 3DP-APP source.

Any help will be very useful.

Thanks in advance!

Partha

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about licensing and legal issues we are neither equipped nor legally qualified to answer, and any ill advice could unintentionally pose a liability to both the user and the network. For official info see the [Blender Licensing Terms and Conditions](https://www.blender.org/about/license/) and the [FAQ about GNU GPL](https://www.blender.org/support/faq/#gnu-gpl)

Answer (score 0):

Blender is completely open source, free to use, free to change, and free to sell. It's one of the beautiful things about it's open source nature. You can create proprietary add-ons written in Python and sell them on your site, or on places like the Blender Marketplace as long as they are distributed under Blender's GPL license.

A good source of info on this sort of thing is Blender.org itself: https://www.blender.org/about/license/

The part that you should be looking at is near the bottom, and is as follows:

> Sharing or selling Blender add-ons (Python scripts) Blender’s Python
> API is an integral part of the software, used to define the user
> interface or develop tools for example. The GNU GPL license therefore
> requires that such scripts (if published) are being shared under a GPL
> compatible license. You are free to sell such scripts, but the sales
> then is restricted to the download service itself. Your customers will
> receive the script under the same license (GPL), with the same free
> conditions as everyone has for Blender.

Given this, the intermediate Python add-on should be distributed under this license because it uses Blender's Python API directly. Conversely, because your 3DP-APP can operate independently from Blender and it's API, it does not need to be made open source.

I would recommend putting the Python add-on up on a public GitHub repository with the GPL license and direct your customers to download it from there just to be safe. That way it is truly open source. Read this thread for more information: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/8836/gplv3-forces-us-to-make-code-available-but-to-whom/8840

You can also find further reading and information about the GNU/GPL license here: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html

**Disclaimer:** I am not a lawyer, I am simply someone who has experience using open source software like Blender with proprietary software for contract work. This is my opinion, not legal advice.